# Entity Framework Could not be found

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

After installing Connector. Net and MySQL visual studio plugin 1.2.7 and MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity I installed Entity Framework, when I want to create Entity Data Model the wizard says "An Entity Framework Database Provider Compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection"
[image]

Comment: Your title contradicts the error message you are getting. EF is there, what is not there is a compatible database provider for MySQL. Have you done everything the message proposes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create Entity Framework 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920869/cant-create-entity-framework-6-x)